# Nginx: How to add a trailing slash to URL except if it starts with certain name

Tags: regex, .htaccess, nginx, redirect

I'm trying to add redirects in nginx config file where if a user lands on any URL except a specific one, it will add a trailing slash after it. Also, it shouldn't add a trailing slash if there's a `.` in it.

Example:

- [www.site.com/foo](http://www.site.com/foo) => [www.site.com/foo/](http://www.site.com/foo/)
- [www.site.com/foo/baz](http://www.site.com/foo/baz) => [www.site.com/foo/baz/](http://www.site.com/foo/baz/)
- [www.site.com/foo.xml](http://www.site.com/foo.xml) => [www.site.com/foo.xml](http://www.site.com/foo.xml) (no trailing slash since there's a `.` in the url)
- [www.site.com/no-trailing-slash](http://www.site.com/no-trailing-slash) => [www.site.com/no-trailing-slash](http://www.site.com/no-trailing-slash) (no trailing slash specifically for this URL)

I did see this already which covers most of what I need:

```
#add trailing slash to all URLs except if it contains a .
rewrite ^([^.])*[^/]$ $1/ permanent;
```

I also figured out how to not add a trailing slash to a specific URL by doing something like this:

```
rewrite ^(?!no-trailing-slash).*[^/]$ $1/ permanent;
```

But I can't figure out how to combine them so that:

1. All redirects will add a trailing `/`
2. Unless they have a `.` in the URL
3. and doesn't start with `/no-trailing-slash URL

Answer (score 1):

Use this with `multi-line flag`:

```
^(.*)(\/(?!no-trailing-slash)([^.\/])+)$
```

Replace any match with:

```
$1$2/
```

The pattern matches anything that after last `/` neither has `.` nor start with specific pattern and add `/` at the end of them.

check [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yawcaX/3)

Comment: This one will add a trailing slash to any URI except the `/no-trailing-slash` rewriting `/foo/` to `/foo//` etc. Use `^(.*)(/(?!no-trailing-slash)([^.])*[^/.])$` to prevent it from adding a trailing slash to the URI already having that slash.

Comment: You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out with the help of HFZ's regex example. I used this and it works perfect:

```
^((?!no-trailing-slash)([^.]*[^\/]))$
```

and replace any match with:

```
$1/
```

Comment: Hi @Alfonse, how can you do it with multiple URLs that should not have trailing slashes

`^((?!no-trailing-slash)(?!no-trailing-slash-1)([^.]*[^\/]))$`

or

`^((?!no-trailing-slash|no-trailing-slash-1)([^.]*[^\/]))$`

Not sure if any of these will work. Thanks!